# Pitstop adding Page Info

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Hopefully someone out there with PitStop experience can help.

I have to merge Millions of variable QR codes into layouts, I'm doing this through XMPie, and outputting PDFs for my layouts.  I have this figured out, this is the easy part.

First, and highest importance, what I need to do is to add a Page Info text line to the margin of every sheet (Page# & File Name).  Is there a way to do this with PitStop?

Second, in the "would be nice" category, if I could add a mark or bar or something on every Xth page to mark for QC checking.  In my case, it would be every 1000th page.  Is that possible with PitStop?

I use PitStop a lot for general preflighting, so I'm familiar with global changes, and creating my own actions, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do these two things.

Comment: This question might just be a bit too software specific for GDSE.  Have you tried the Enfocus Forum? https://forum.enfocus.com/

Comment: I was waiting for my account to be approved.  I'd been waiting for XMPie to work with me on it, since I pay for annual support, but it's been over 2 weeks, I have to start production on Monday next week, and the only thing I've heard from them is "we're looking into it".  that said, I think I figured it out, running a few more tests, but if I have got it, I'll answer it myself as soon as I can.  It's not super fast, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did figure out how to do it with a global action.

select every Nth page and add the block on the sheet edge:

[image: Select Ever Nth Page]

[image: Add Rectangle]

Then select all the pages and add footer to every page with page count and other text:

[image: Select all the Pages]

[image: Add footer text]

Use the "Variable" box to add things like document name, current page number and total page count.